# Implementing the DNNLinearCombinedRegressor model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, regression

I am trying to implement the wide and deep tensorflow model for regression (DNNLinearCombinedRegressor). Here is the overview of the code that I used

```
def input_function(num_epochs, train_set):
#defined input function for training.

def build_model_col():
# for conversion of input pandas columns into tenforflow feature columns. also created embedding columns for a few columns. 
    return wide_column, deep_column

def build_estimator(model_dir):
    wide_columns, deep_columns = build_model_col()
    hidden_units = [1024, 512, 256]
    return tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedRegressor(
       model_dir = model_dir,
       linear_feature_columns = wide_columns,
       dnn_feature_columns = deep_columns,
       dnn_hidden_units = hidden_units)

test_data = pd.read_csv(...)
def main():
    shutil.rmtree(modeldir)
    model = build_estimator(modeldir)
    model.train(input_function = lambda: input_function(200, test_data))

if __name__ = "__main__":
    main()
```

The loss (mean_squared_error) never came less than 1000 in any of the steps. This is way to high and there is some error since the maximum value of "y" in the training dataset is only 40, with the minimum being 0.

I am probably missing something. I searched a lot but did not come across a single reproducible example of DNNLinearCombinedRegressor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute loss value doesn't usually mean much.

If you only do reduce_sum for the loss instead of reduce_mean then increasing the batch size increases the absolute loss value.

Take a few examples out, run the model and see what the output is. There might be some trivial bug in your data. Change your input a bit and see how the prediction changes. Take say a few hundred random examples (from your test set), get the prediction and compare it yourself.